# Tkinter - How to update frames and the parameter between each frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need some help with updating informations between two or more frames in tkinter. I am currelty working on a small project, where I have serval frames with information, each frame is one class.

First frame is a setting frame - so where the user can click some buttons and select several things.
The second frame should show the selected image with the made choices. 
So far I can make the choices on the setting page but when i click forward to the result page it shows me empty frames and no image and not the made choices.

I tried to do some shared_data with the information that should be passed between the two frames/classes, so I can acess them on the resultpage but some how it is not updating the information. So it doesn't show me the image because mode on the results page is 0 like at the beginng.

```
class xyz (tk.Tk):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      ...
      self.shared_data = {
          "no": tk.IntVar(),
          "selectedname": tk.StringVar(),
          "selectedpath": tk.StringVar(),
          .....
       }

      container = tk.Frame(self)
      container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
      container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
      container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

      self.frames = {}

      for F in (SettingPage, PageResults):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[page_name] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

       self.show_frame("SettingPage")

   def show_frame(self, page_name):
       frame = self.frames[page_name]
       frame.tkraise()


class SettingPage(tk.Frame):

   def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
      self.controller = controller

      self.controller.shared_data["no"] = 0

      ...

      # after selecting serval buttons
      self.controller.shared_data["no"] = 1

      buttonContinue = ttk.Button(self, text='''CONTINUE >>''', command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageResults"))
      buttonContinue.place(relx=0.84, rely=0.9, height=43, width=186)


class PageResults(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, controller):

      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.controller = controller

      mode =  self.controller.shared_data["no"]

      if mode == 1 :

         #     show image
         #......
```

I can't show you the exact real code I am using so I tried so simplify it. I am new to tkinter so any help would be much apprechiated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you do this:

```
self.shared_data = {
    "no": tk.IntVar(),
    ...
}
```

And then later you do this:

```
self.controller.shared_data["no"] = 0
```

So, `shared_data["no"]` starts out as an `IntVar` and then you ***replace*** it with an integer.

When you use an `IntVar` you must use the `set` method to change the value, and the `get` method to get the value:

```
self.controller.shared_data["no"].set(0)
...
if self.controller.shared_data["no"] == 0:
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you - I changed it in my code but unfortunatley it didn't solve the problem yet. The second frame doens't update the information that the value of "no" got changed on the settingpage
So the frame is once initialized with the value 0, so the  

     if self.controller.shared_data["no"].get() == 1:
     # show image

still doesn't show me the image because its still false. Any other ideas?